# Parse date for datepicker to show event dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, datepicker

Ok so what i am trying to achieve is parse numbers of dates into datepicker and then show it. Simple . I am able to do it for chrome but in firefox i am having some issue .
      dates are coming from ajax like this .

```
     var eventDates ={};
     //lets take some demo entry 
     var dates = [{datename:'2015-04-15 10:39:57'},{datename:'2015-04-18 10:39:57'}]  

     jQuery.each(dates ,function(key,val){
       eventDates[new Date(moment(val.datename).format('MM-DD-YYYY'))] = new Date(moment(val.datename).format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
      })
     console.log(eventDates);
     jQuery('#calendar').datepicker({
         beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var highlight = eventDates[date];
            console.log(highlight);
            if (highlight) {
                 return [true, "event", highlight];
            } else {
                 return [true, '', ''];
            }
         },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            location.href = '/schedule';
        }

    });
```

So above solution works perfectly for chrome but when it comes to firefox undefined date error get throwed.

I have tried some ways to parse date for firefox , which works well in chrome .

```
//method 1
eventDates[Date.parse(moment(val.date).format('MM-DD-YYYY'))] = Date.parse(moment(val.date).format('MM-DD-YYYY'));

//method 2 
eventDates[moment(val.date)] =moment(val.date);
```

for second method dates are coming for firefox but don't get showed in datepicker. But it works for chrome. Ugh . Any suggestion for firefox.

Any help ? Tell me if i am lost somewhere .

**Update**

So take from this is , datepicker has it's own method for parsing dates. I have shown some strange object strings in above example , But take from this would be use datepicker parse method.

Comment: To my knowledge there are no incompatibility issues between Chrome and Firefox regarding `Date`. Maybe the problem is not actually in your code. Use basic debugging to see what Firefox does.

Comment: See  console.log(highlight); it  always show undefined for firefox, even eventDates have entries for dates. And same solution works in chrome .

Comment: Perhaps Firefox serializes dates differently, causing a mismatch? Verify what is in `eventDates`. Note that you can't use objects as keys, they will get cast to a string. Without specifying the format that seems risky.

Comment: It does seem strange to use date objects as keys in an object.

Comment: @adeneo It is sample data string. . SO it may be strange ;)

Comment: `2015-04-15 10:39:57` isn't  a valid date string and also doesn't match the format passed to moment

Comment: Try it like this instead -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/eexp67wu/**, removes the need for Moment, as $.datepicker parses dates just fine, and fixes some strange issues in your code.

Comment: Thanks @adeneo It works :) . appreciated .

Comment: I'll add that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an object with date objects as keys and values, a really strange object, but comparing date objects that way should work in theory as `toValue` is called on them, but it's still a little strange.

Also, jQuery's datepicker has a built in way to parse dates that does basically the same as Moment.

Rewritten it would look like this instead

```
var dates = [{
    'date': '2015-04-15 10:39:57'
}, {
    'date': '2015-04-18 10:39:57'
}]

var eventDates = jQuery.map(dates, function (val) {
    return $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', val.date.split(' ').shift()).getTime();
});

jQuery('#calendar').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return eventDates.indexOf(date.getTime()) != -1 ? [true, "event", date] : [true, '', '']
    },
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        location.href = '/schedule';
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/eexp67wu/)